# How to apply cast in postgres values expression with JOOQ

Tags: postgresql, jooq

For large 'in' conditions in Postgres the following

> IN (VALUES ('a'),('b'),('c'))

can lead to much more efficient query plans than

> IN ('a','b','c')

In JOOQ I can express this with

```
Field f = ...  
Row1[] rows = new Row1[array.length];
for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    rows[i] = DSL.row(array[i]);
Condition c = f.in(DSL.selectFrom(DSL.values(rows)));
```

But what if I need to cast the values? To be more specific, when comparing values with a citext column at least one of the values needs to be explicitly cast to citext for the query to work. Example:

```
select distinct "x0"."pk"
from "sometable" as "x0"
 where "x0"."external_shared_id" in ( values 
       ('ext0308174863'::citext),
     ('ext1560238348'))
```

How can I write this with JOOQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no documented way to create custom data types for usage in casts. You could use internal API at your own risk, which I won't document here. I've created a feature request to create such `DataType` references:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11806

An explicit feature request for `citext` support is here:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5934

As always, [when jOOQ is missing support for vendor specific functionality plain SQL templating is your friend](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/). So, just do this:

```java
rows[i] = row(field("{0}::citext", String.class, val(array[i])));
```

Assuming the following static import:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```