# Custom type for create table statement in JOOQ

Tags: java, jooq

I am trying to create a runtime DDL script for a postgresql database using jooq, this DDL script includes the use of Postgresql types such as "regclass".

I tried using `DSL.field("reference regclass")` or similar approaches, but the end result usually ends as something like:

```sql
create table meta_reference(id uuid, reference regclass any);
```

I saw other questions but those usually involves situations where casting is allowed, which is not the case for table creation or similar DDL scripts.

It seems that the `.column` part of `DSL.createTable` uses the `dataType` of the given field. I was thinking about implementing the `DataType` interface myself, but there are too many methods to override, I would like to know if implementing `DataType` is the only way or if there are other ways (such as `Binding`s) to create such script and achieve something like this:

```sql
create table meta_reference(id uuid, reference regclass);
```

I understand that the "regclass" type could be considered a bad example, because it is just a glorified int/bigint with some checks (but its integrity fails, like for example, when dropping tables), but the same logic above could be applied to any vendor-specific type or user-defined-type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a pending feature request for this:

- [#11806](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11806) Add API to create plain SQL DataType instances
- [How to apply cast in postgres values expression with JOOQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67275840/how-to-apply-cast-in-postgres-values-expression-with-jooq) (related question)

In the meantime, you could create your own `DefaultDataType`, though beware, this means using internal API, which might break in the future (especially, once [#11806](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11806) is implemented)

Comment: A related extension to the question: Is `DataType` considered public api? I am asking because I am considering "properly" implementing these data types, or at least the ones that I will be using extensively. Thanks for the quick reply Lukas

Comment: @LouizFC: Can you ask a new question, please? I'd like to elaborate with details, that's hard in the comments.

Comment: I created a new question as asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76514838