# When using JOOQ, is the DataType interface considered "public api" for implementation?

Tags: java, jooq

This is an extension of this question: [Custom type for create table statement in JOOQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76509358)

As of JOOQ 3.18.4, when one looks at the `DataType` interface, there seems to be no "extension point" for implementing new `DataType`s, which would be useful for implementing user-defined or vendor-specific data types.

There are already issues related to this (see https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11806)

So my question is: as of now, could the `DataType` interface be considered "internal", but is public for implementation reasons (like an sealed interface before that was a thing), or it could be considered "public" and up to new client code implementations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jOOQ is a very opinionated API with respect to object orientation and how you should interact with it. In particular, you should hardly implement any types yourself if they're not clearly designated for extension purposes.

Extensible API elements include:

- [`ExecuteListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ExecuteListener.html) and many other listeners registered with the [`Configuration`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Configuration.html) as well as other SPIs from `Configuration`
- Anything that starts with `Custom`, e.g. [`CustomQueryPart`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/CustomQueryPart.html), see [custom syntax elements](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-queryparts/)
- Anything that starts with `Default`, such as [`DefaultConnection`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/tools/jdbc/DefaultConnection.html) (these can usually work without extension, but do allow it)
- Anything that starts with `Abstract`, such as [`AbstractConverter`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/dev/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/AbstractConverter.html) (these are meant to be extended, and can't work by themselves, being `abstract`)

There's a special case that you shouldn't extend manually yourself, but indirectly via your generated code, including:

- Any base type for generated code, such as [`TableImpl`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/TableImpl.html)

That's it. Everything else is not supposed to be extended, and in fact, this information will be formally conveyed in the future by sealing the type hierarchy (see e.g. details of [#14756](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14756)).

This official take is also documented here, in the [manual's section about semantic versioning and compatibility](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/semantic-versioning/), specifically:

> jOOQ's DSL interfaces should not be implemented by client code! Extend only those extension points that are explicitly documented as "extendable" (e.g. [custom QueryParts](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-queryparts/)).

To answer your specific question, `DataType` is part of jOOQ's DSL and not meant for extension. Of course, as long as it is not a `sealed` type yet, you can do it. The sealing won't happen in a minor release in order not to break client code. But do note that in every minor release, there will be new methods that will break your implementation, so if you still implement your own, know what you're doing. Also, you might run into an occasional `ClassCastException`, because jOOQ occasionally assumes you don't extend its types, so it unsafely casts a public API type to an internal type that you can't access.

It's not unlikely that you have a use-case that could be implemented entirely differently, or with new generic SPIs and extension points, so perhaps, [a feature request](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose) might be the best way forward here